# WebRTC works locally, but not over Internet

Tags: webrtc

I'm trying to get a simple proof of concept WebRTC app going. I've got code that works on the local network, but not over the Internet.

I believe I've got a bug [outlined here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34217462/webrtc-connects-on-local-connection-but-fails-over-internet), but I can't figure it out.

server.js (expressjs)

```js
require('dotenv').config();

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.use(express.static('public'));

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.on('join', () => socket.broadcast.emit('join', socket.id));
    socket.on('offer', (id, sdp) => socket.to(id).emit('offer', socket.id, sdp));
    socket.on('answer', (id, sdp) => socket.to(id).emit('answer', socket.id, sdp));
    socket.on('candidate', (id, candidate) => socket.to(id).emit('candidate', socket.id, candidate));
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 443;
http.listen(port, () => console.log("listening on :" + port));
```

client.js (built w/ webpack)

```js
import io from 'socket.io-client';

console.log('getting video stream');
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true }).then(myStream => {
    const socket = io.connect();

    console.log('joining');
    socket.emit('join');

    let connections = {};

    socket.on('join', async peer_id => {
        const connection = newConnection(peer_id);

        console.log('creating offer');
        const sdp = await connection.createOffer();

        console.log('setting local desc');
        await connection.setLocalDescription(sdp);

        console.log('sending offer');
        socket.emit('offer', peer_id, connection.localDescription);
    });

    socket.on('offer', async (peer_id, remoteDescription) => {
        const connection = newConnection(peer_id);

        console.log('setting remote desc');
        await connection.setRemoteDescription(remoteDescription);

        console.log('creating answer');
        const sdp = await connection.createAnswer();

        console.log('setting local desc');
        await connection.setLocalDescription(sdp);

        console.log('sending answer');
        socket.emit('answer', peer_id, connection.localDescription);
    });

    socket.on('answer', (peer_id, remoteDescription) => {
        console.log('setting remote desc');
        connections[peer_id].setRemoteDescription(remoteDescription);
    });

    socket.on('candidate', (peer_id, candidate) => {
        console.log('adding candidate');
        connections[peer_id].addIceCandidate(candidate);
    });

    function newConnection(peer_id) {
        console.log('creating connection');
        const connection = new RTCPeerConnection(
            { iceServers: [{ urls: ['stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'] }] }
        );

        connections[peer_id] = connection;

        connection.onconnectionstatechange = () => console.log('connection state', connection.connectionState);

        console.log('searching for candidates');
        connection.onicecandidate = event => {
            if (event.candidate) {
                console.log('sending candidate');
                socket.emit('candidate', peer_id, event.candidate);
            } else {
                console.log('all candidates found');
            }
        };

        console.log('listening for tracks');
        connection.ontrack = event => {
            console.log('track received');
            const stream = new MediaStream();
            stream.addTrack(event.track);
            document.getElementById('video').srcObject = stream;
        };

        for (const track of myStream.getTracks()) {
            console.log('sending track');
            connection.addTrack(track);
        }

        return connection;
    }
});
```

### Logs from local network peers (connected)

first peer

```
getting video stream
joining
creating connection
searching for candidates
listening for tracks
sending track
creating offer
setting local desc
sending offer
(2) sending candidate
setting remote desc
adding candidate
track received
connection state connecting
all candidates found
connection state connected
```

second peer

```
getting video stream
joining
creating connection
searching for candidates
listening for tracks
sending track
setting remote desc
track received
creating answer
setting local desc
sending answer
sending candidate
connection state connecting
all candidates found
connection state connected
(2) adding candidate
```

### Logs from peers over the Internet (failed)

first peer

```
getting video stream
joining
creating connection
searching for candidates
listening for tracks
sending track
creating offer
setting local desc
sending offer
(3) sending candidate
all candidates found
setting remote desc
track received
connection state connecting
(5) adding candidate
connection state failed
```

second peer

```
getting video stream
joining
creating connection
searching for candidates
listening for tracks
sending track
setting remote desc
track received
creating answer
setting local desc
sending answer
(5) sending candidate
(3) adding candidate
connection state connecting
connection state failed
all candidates found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebRTC isn't going to work on all connection pairings unless you use TURN.

You will see some peers able to connect though, you can read about all the cases that matter in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59906509/how-do-you-get-around-nats-using-webrtc-without-a-turn-server/59906573#59906573)

Comment: Wouldn't I be able to get at least one combination of clients to connect? I've tried the permutations of my home internet, my phone 5g, and a Verizon hotspot.

Comment: Is there something particular I should be looking for in chrome://webrtc-internals/? I see two udp and one tcp (ipv4) candidates on each client. And they are properly added to their peers. If there a way that I can see the status of any of those candidates?

Comment: I went ahead and tried out some Twilio turn servers, and the code is working right. So, I guess I can give up hope there is a bug in here. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Happy to help! It is hard to track down because it depends on each connection (and they may interact with each differently). If you have two peers using the same ISP they may have a different NAT type etc... https://github.com/enobufs/go-nats is a cool tool that might be helpful!